# Несоответствие родов сказуемого и подлежащего

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, согласование, сказуемые, подлежащее

Скажите, соответствует ли литературной норме такое предложение?

*Судя по виду Михалыча, на улице была метель, а то и целый буран.*

Если бы вместо "метель" и "буран" тут были, например, "дождь" и "ливень", всё было бы верно (при замене "была" на "был", конечно). Но поскольку глагол "была" относится и к метели, и к бурану, предложение кажется мне построенным неправильно. Подскажите соответствующее правило, если такое есть.

Comment: Нормально так вроде. Не обязательно должны роды совпадать, по-моему. Написал комментарием как раз потому, что не могу аргументировать или привести примеры.

Comment: _Соответствует ли литературной норме такое предложение?_ === Соответствует. Посмотрите §190 вот здесь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

Comment: @slava1947. Почему бы Вам не оформить это как ответ? Тогда вопрос можно будет закрыть и Community не будет его бесконечно возвращать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сказуемое ставится во множественном числе, если возникает необходимость согласования в роде и подлежащие принадлежат к разному грамматическому роду, например: ...Ни одно государство или группа государств не должны получить военное преимущество; Действие или признак субъекта (подлежащего) выражены сказуемым; Статья в целом или отрывок из нее представили бы интерес для читателей сборника.

**Если между однородными подлежащими стоят противительные союзы, возможна двоякая форма согласования:**

***1)      постпозитивное сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим, обозначающим реальный (не отрицаемый) предмет, например: Не ты, но судьба виновата (Лермонтов); Роман, а не повесть будет опубликован в журнале; Не роман, а повесть будет опубликована в журнале.***

**2)      препозитивное сказуемое согласуется с ближайшим подлежащим (независимо от того, является ли оно утверждаемым или отрицательным), например: *Меня угнетала не боль, а тяжелое, тупое недоумение (Горький); Опубликован роман, а не повесть, Опубликован не роман, а повесть; Это была не разведка, а настоящее сражение.***
[Розенталь](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm) §190 п.2

У Вас препозитивное сказуемое, поэтому БЫЛА МЕТЕЛЬ, А ТО И ЦЕЛЫЙ БУРАН.